# Subsonic 3.0 SQLite FormatException parsing DateTime?

Tags: subsonic

I have an MS Access database, which I have converted to an SQLite database. I have SubSonic setup and working, and I can pull data out of the database successfully into a WinForms app using ActiveRecord. All except for one table.

I get a FormatException, "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". The format of the date column in the database is DD/MM/YYYY.

I'm not even trying to do anything too complicated:

```
 var allOrders = order.All();

 foreach (order o in allOrders)
 {
   listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", o.OrderDate.HasValue ? o.OrderDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty, o.Product));
 }
```

I'm not exactly sure why the problem is manifesting in the first place :(

Comment: when you query the OrderDate column with plain old SQL does the date come back in the form of DD/MM/YYYY ?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has "interesting" ways of formatting dates - you have to be very, very sure that you're getting back what you think you are because normally it's not DD/MM/YYYY - it's the opposite if I recall.

Comment: Well, I can only assume something went wrong when I converted the MS Access .mdb to an SQLite db.

As per @Roberto's suggestion:

sqlite> select OrderDate from orders
   ...> limit 5;
1024009200000
1024009200000
1024009200000
1024009200000
1024009200000

I've never seen Date/Time like that before. I'm thinking that the tool I used to convert the database is at fault here.

Comment: So I was kinda right about the database conversion tool I used mangling the date. http://code.google.com/p/mdb-sqlite/ is what I used - I hacked on the source, and modified it so that it converts the date column value to a string. After converting the database again, querying using sqlite3.exe gives a date in the OrderDate column as this: Fri Aug 22 00:00:00 BST 2008

But, I'm still getting the FormatException, but now I think it's because the System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader can't see that string as a valid date because of the 'BST'.